# What are Ruby debugger tricks, tweaks, and best practices?

Tags: ruby, debugging

I was looking for a list of best practices with the Ruby's `rdb` but found none.

What are your favorite rdb tricks, best practices, and/or tweaks to get more out of the Ruby debugger?

Comment: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rdebug/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at some of the `auto` commands like `set autolist`, `set autoeval`, or `set autoirb` in the [ruby-debug reference manual](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug/ruby-debug.html)

The `--post-mortem` or `-m` option can sometimes be useful for raw Ruby programs, that is not in a framework which often adds its own uncaught-exception handler.

`set different` is also something that to my knowledge started with ruby-debug.

The rewrites or ruby-debug:

- [rb-trepanning](https://github.com/rocky/rb-trepanning/wiki) for a patched 1.9.2 YARV
- [rbx-trepanning](https://github.com/rocky/rbx-trepanning/wiki) for Rubinius, and
- [rb8-trepanning](https://github.com/rocky/rb8-trepanning/wiki) for MRI 1.8

have `eval` (no arguments) and `eval?` which evaluate the current source line without stepping the program. The wiki also lists other cool features of each.

They also have syntax coloring of source text and debugger output.